# How to use a Google Service Account to authenticate via IAM in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-iam, triggers

- I am writing a Google Apps Script
- I'd like to make an https call to an external server.
- This server happens to be on GCP (Google Cloud Platform) and sitting
  behind IAM.

In order to be able to authenticate with the server, I need to pass an Authorization Bearer header. My problem is, what do I pass as the Authorization Bearer?

From what I understand, I have 2 options that I've tried and failed at:

1. Use the default GSA `appsdev-apps-dev-script-auth@system.gserviceaccount.com.` and grant it IAM permissions (that didn't work).
2. Create a custom GSA, save the private token in the Apps Scripts Properties. However, how do I convert that token to a JWT so I can use it for the Authorization Bearer

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/authenticate-via-oauth-2-access-token AND https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/authenticate-with-a-service-account

Comment: This is with Firebase authentication and it is deprecated :(

Comment: Do you have a link that shows my links as deprecated? OAuth is NOT deprecated and is the primary authorization method in Google Cloud.

Comment: You completely misunderstood my comment. I was not referring to OAuth. In the service account link you sent, it says: "Firebase legacy tokens are the easiest way to authenticate to your Firebase Realtime Database but are deprecated and not recommended by Google."

Also, these links seem to be for connecting to Firebase and not a google service behind IAM, am I misunderstand this?

Comment: Please read the links in my comment. I think you misunderstand what is legacy. The first link is the easy way, the second link uses a service account. Firebase legacy tokens are legacy, not OAuth.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].